# How to convert for-in loop into foreach in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one for loop where I found index in repeating hence I want to convert into foreach loop.

```
for (key, _) in details {
    let product = product
    details[key]?.title = product.first?.name ?? ""
    details[key]?.amount = Double(product.first?.prices ?? 0.0)
}
```

I tried this as below but still here details[key]? is repeating

```
details.forEach { key, value in
   let product = product
   details[key]?.title = cartProduct.first?.name ?? ""
   details[key]?.amount = Double(product.first?.prices ?? 0.0)
}
```

May I know, how to convert this into foreach in Swift so that I don't need to write [key] every-time.

Comment: What does `let product = product` mean? Either it's reference type then the properties are mutable anyway, or it's value type then assigning an immutable object to an immutable object is nonsensical. And to call it multiple times inside a loop doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
    details.forEach { _, value in
        value value = value // Add this if your `value` is a struct
        let product = product
        value.title = cartProduct.first?.name ?? ""
        value.amount = Double(product.first?.prices ?? 0.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
details.forEach { 
    var mutableProduct = $0
    let product = product
    mutableProduct.value.title = cartProduct.first?.name ?? ""
    mutableProduct.value.amount = Double(product.first?.prices ?? 0.0)
}
```